# volcanic CO₂ emission estimates increasing

Tags: climate-change

I just read that estimates of CO₂ emissions form volcanos has increased from 100Mt to 600Mt/ year in the last decade or so. While still only a fraction of the natural cycle, in what ways does this sort of change affect understanding of where CO₂ emissions are coming from?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. If you want use to  investigate whether the volcano emissions have actually changed, please provide a reference to where you read it. How it "affects understanding" is too open a question.

Comment: If you mean "does this affect (if true) our understanding of whether the rise in atmospheric CO2 is anthropogenic or natural?"  then the answer is "no, no really".  The amount involved is too small to affect the mass balance analysis given in my answer to a related question http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/is-co2-the-cause-for-global-warming/17707#17707 .  The Earth Science forum (http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) might be a better venue.  HTH.